# how to create an object which takes as a parameter another object using python

Tags: python

I want to create my own logging class: which writes some data to a text file.

For this I have made a class mylog.py

I want to be able to create an instance object of the mylog.py class an pass the instance object as a paremeter to the other classes I have written.

However when I try to access the mylog object using the self notation and without using the self notation I am having issues.

The issue is that when I refer to the mylog object in the startup class and use self.log = logger this doesn't work to use the methods of the mylog class like self.log.write() nor does setting logobj to a variable without self and passing that in.

**My mylog.py class**

```
import datetime
import os

class logtextfile(object):


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def write(self,**kwargs):
        """Writes a log message to a user specified file which indicates the action takes and if it was successful"""
        self.file = kwargs.get('file',"log.txt")
        self.loglevel = kwargs.get('loglevel',"critical")
        self.logmessage = kwargs.get('logmessage',"error")
        self.success = kwargs.get('success',False)
        self.class_name = kwargs.get('class',str("{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)))
        self.output = ", ".join([str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0,microsecond=0)),self.class_name,str(self.logmessage),str(self.success),str("\n")])

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

        f = open(str(self.file),"a")
        f.write(self.output)
        f.close()

    def now(self, filename, openas, data):
        """Creates a log file with todays date and time"""
        fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'
        fn = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=filename)
        f = open(str(fn),openas)
        f.write(data + "\n")
        f.close()
```

**My startup class**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import datetime
import requests
import lxml
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import timeit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
from zenlog import log

class company(object):

    def __init__(self, name, logobj):
        self.name = name
        logger = logobj

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def listed(self):
        try:
            #all companies on asx downloaded from asx website csv
            self.function_name = str("{}".format(self.__class__.__name__))
            df = pd.read_csv('http://asx.com.au/asx/research/ASXListedCompanies.csv', skiprows=1)
            df.columns = ["company","asx_code","industry"]
            df["yahoo_code"] = df["asx_code"]+".AX"
            message = "succesfully downloaded ASXListedCompanies.csv"
            logger.write(file="asx_module_log.txt",logmessage=message,success=True)
            return df
        except:
            message = "ASXListedCompanies.csv could not be retrieved, the website is unavailable"
            try:
                logger.write(file="asx_module_log.txt",logmessage=message)
            except:
                log.critical(message)

    def valid(self):
        try:
            df = self.listed()
            return df[(df["industry"]!= "Not Applic") & (df["industry"]!="Class Pend")]
        except:
            message = "Could not retrieve listed companies object with pandas dataframe"
            try:
                logfile.write(file="asx_module_log.txt",logmessage=message)
            except:
                log.critical(message)

    def invalid(self):
        try:
            df = self.listed()
            return df[(df["industry"]=="Not Applic") | (df["industry"]=="Class Pend")]
        except:
            message = "Could not retrieve listed companies object with pandas dataframe"
            try:
                logfile.write(file="asx_module_log.txt",logmessage=message)
            except:
                log.critical(message)
```

**my code to create an instance of mylog and pass it to the startup class so that it can log to the textfile.**

```
import mylog
import startup

logger = mylog.logtextfile(name="mylogfile")

c = startup.company(name="mycompany",logobj=logger)
df = c.invalid()
df.head()
```

Comment: *What* "issues"?

Comment: Also, what is `mylog()`? And fix your indentation.

Comment: mylog is my logging class which contains logtextfile, and my second class lets call it startup contains the class company. I want to supply an instance of the mylog class to the startup class and each of the other classes I write so they all log to the one text file sequentially.

Comment: @yoshiserry you're neither describing your "issues" nor providing a minimal complete verifiable example. No one can possibly help you without those informations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated.

Comment: **1** Your indentation is still broken. **2** Don't bury imports in the middle of your script, put them at the top. And it'd make your code easier to read if you used PEP-8 style for your class names, eg `Company` and `LogTextFile`. **3** What's `mylog`? And why doesn't that code create an instance of `logtextfile`? Please make your code a [mcve].

Comment: the code doesn't create the instance because creating the instance is not my problem, as I describe in the question passing an object of class X to another class and being able to use object X inside the second class method is the issue.

Comment: @PM2Ring updated mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test your `company` class: I don't have most of those 3rd-party modules. However, it's generally a bad idea to have "naked" `except` clauses. Use named exceptions, otherwise you may be catching things that you don't expect.

Anyway, here's a short demo of using your logger in an instance of another class.

```
import datetime

class LogTextfile(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def write(self, **kwargs):
        """ Writes a log message to a user specified file which
            indicates the action takes and if it was successful
        """
        self.file = kwargs.get('file', "log.txt")
        self.loglevel = kwargs.get('loglevel', "critical")
        self.logmessage = kwargs.get('logmessage', "error")
        self.success = kwargs.get('success', False)
        self.class_name = kwargs.get('class', str("{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)))
        self.output = ", ".join([str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)),
            self.class_name, str(self.logmessage), str(self.success), str("\n")])

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        f = open(str(self.file), "a")
        f.write(self.output)
        f.close()

    def now(self, filename, openas, data):
        """Creates a log file with todays date and time"""
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'
        fn = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=filename)
        f = open(str(fn), openas)
        f.write(data + "\n")
        f.close()

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def logtest(self, message):
        self.logger.write(logmessage=message)


logger = LogTextfile(name="mylogfile")
logger.write(logmessage='This is a test')

t = Test(logger)
t.logtest('Message from Test')
```

**contents of "log.txt"**

```
2017-05-04 22:40:00, LogTextfile, This is a test, False, 
2017-05-04 22:40:00, LogTextfile, Message from Test, False,
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class A(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x


class B(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        if (isinstance(a, A)):
            self.x = a.x
        else:
            self.x = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(10)
    b = B(a)
```